# Not able to run TestNG programmatically (Not able to create executable JAR)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, executable-jar

I want to create a executable jar from selenium testNg code

```
 import org.testng.TestNG;
import com.test.Utility.ExtentReporterNG;

public class TestRunner {
    static TestNG testNg;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExtentReporterNG ext = new ExtentReporterNG();
        TestNG testNg = new TestNG();
        testNg.setTestClasses(new Class[] { LoginTest.class });
        testNg.addListener(ext);
        testNg.run();
    }
}
```

It contains 3 test cases within LoginTest class but its giving below error while executing:

===============================================
Command line suite
Total tests run: 3, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 3

## Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line of code :

```
testNg.addListener(ext);
```

Replace with:

```
testNg.addListener((ITestNGListener)ext);
```

It will work fine

Note :

I assume that you write reporting logic in your ExtentReporterNG class which implements IReporter